# Associating Linux driver with a device tree node

Tags: linux-device-driver, device-tree

I have a Device Tree enabled kernel (v. 4.9...) for TI AM335, and need to use a TMP102 i2c device. The driver is /drivers/hwmon/tmp102.c. 
But the .c file does not have any device tree style association. 
Just the normal `MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(i2c, tmp102_id)` where the id string is "tmp102".

Other custom drivers for the same kernel have DT style association: `MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(of, dt_ids)` where id string is in "vendor,device" form matching the .dts file. It also has `MODULE_ALIAS("of:vendor,device")`.

I can patch the in-kernel driver and add MODULE_ALIAS or MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE to match the dts id. But are there other ways, like editing some config file?

Comment: That version of that driver does not appear to be fully DT ready.  Look at that driver in kernel version 4.12, which does define the string `"ti,tmp102"` for the compatible property in your Device Tree.  You may have to backport these changes.

Comment: Thanks @sawdust. But again, in 4.12 the string is "ti,tmp102", and in the dts it is "ti,tmp101". The datasheet says 102 is compatible to 101. So is it possible to assign the driver to "ti,tmp101" without changes in the .c file?  I cannot change  the .dts, it is owned by someone else.

Comment: I fail to understand what you mean by a **.dts** file that is *"owned by someone else"*, and why you couldn't modify it.  Now you're contradicting yourself.  First it was *"I can patch the in-kernel driver"*, but now it's *"... without changes in the .c file"*?  You will have to change source code somewhere.  The driver can have more than one compatible string.

Comment: Owned by someone else here means: provided by other team, too much trouble to ask them change it. I can change the kernel drivers (yes, c files) but would prefer configuration of existing binary. Seems that it may be done in /lib/modules/<version>/modules.alias - but I don't understand the syntax completely. Can this file be auto clobbered and my additions lost?

Comment: Well, I had to modify the tmp102.c anyway, so just added the MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE by same occasion. it works.